# convert a fasta file to a tab-delimited file using python script

Tags: python, parsing

I am student currently learning how to write scripts in python. I have been giving the following exercise. I have to convert a fasta file in the following format:

```
>header 1 
AATCTGTGTGATAT 
ATATA  
AT
>header 2  
AATCCTCT
```

into this:

```
>header 1  AATCTGTGTGATATATATAAT
>header 2  AATCCTCT
```

I am having some difficulty getting rid of the white space (using line.strip()?) Any help would be very much appreciated...

Comment: `line.strip()` is certainly useful for this task, but you should post your attempt at coding this, preferably in the form of a [mcve]. We can't help you debug code that we can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a new string based on the `>` character and combines the string until the next `>`.  It then appends to a running list.

```
# open file and iterate through the lines, composing each single line as we go
out_lines = []
temp_line = ''
with open('path/to/file','r') as fp:
     for line in fp:
         if line.startswith('>'):
             out_lines.append(temp_line)
             temp_line = line.strip() + '\t'
         else:
             temp_line += line.strip()

with open('path/to/new_file', 'w') as fp_out:
    fp_out.write('\n'.join(out_lines))
```

Comment: Thanks for this James, very helpful to see how you did this. I am trying to understand as best as possible what you have done, line by line. I have added comments to your script and pasted below: